# android: How can I send an activity to background & call her from there

Tags: android, background, android-activity, minimize

I am in process of  creating some test application "Time Tracker" app like stopwatch so I start app go to Activity where I start time counter and  now  I need some functionality   to send my activity  to background or minimize or  hide  and  after some period  to call this  activity again and  stop her counter to get passed time period .

How can I send Activity to back and call her to front but not  to stop timer counter ??

Comment: i never know, activity is female.. :D... Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Using a Service would be the best way I guess. You can than call `finish()` on your Activity and the Service can start your application when a specific time was reached.

Comment: Hi WarrenFaith ,  I  was  thinking  about  service ,  but first to ask here maybe there is simplest solution.

And in  this  app i need to call activity from background on  some  event click or  something  and  after that  to see time elapsed and  I  can choose to stop time counter,   I mean I need to call activity on my event not to service specified time reached :)

Comment: Easy doing: Service creates a notification in the notification bar and the app starts when the user clicks. :)

Comment: hmmm  interesting  solution  with notification  bar , I  just  testing  wit it , thanks :)